# Split Encoder and Decoder part in AUTOENCODER with skip connections - KERAS

Tags: keras, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

I am trying to implement AUTOENCODER with skip connections and split the Encoder and Decoder parts. So, I can work on latent space and Decoder part.
Below is the architecture in keras I used:

```
## ENCODER    
inputs_encoder = Input(shape = (256, 642))
C1 = Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C1')(inputs_encoder)
D1 = AvgPool1D(pool_size=2)(C1)
C2 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C2')(D1)
D2 = AvgPool1D(pool_size=2)(C2)
C3 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C3')(D2)
D3 = AvgPool1D(pool_size=2)(C3)
C4 = Conv1D(filters=64,  kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C4')(D3)
F = Flatten()(C4)
outputs = Dense(32, activation="relu")(F)
UNet_encoder = Model(inputs_encoder, [outputs, C1, C2, C3, C4], name='UNet_encoder')
    

## DECODER
inputs_decoder = Input(shape=(32))
C1             = Input(shape=(256, 512))
C2             = Input(shape=(128, 256))
C3             = Input(shape=(64, 128))
C4             = Input(shape=(32, 64))
X = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(inputs_decoder)
X = Reshape(target_shape=(32, 64))(X)
C5 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C5')(X)
C5 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([C4, C5])
U  = UpSampling1D(size = 2)(C5)
C6 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C6')(U)
C6 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([C3, C6])
U  = UpSampling1D(size = 2)(C6)
C7 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C7')(U)
C7 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([C2, C7])
U  = UpSampling1D(size = 2)(C7)
C8 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='relu', name='C8')(U)
C8 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([C1, C8])
outputs = Conv1D(filters=642, kernel_size=5,  padding='same', activation='linear')(C8)
UNet_decoder = Model([inputs_decoder, C1, C2, C3, C4], outputs, name='UNet_decoder')

## AUTOENCODER with skip conncetions
Autoencoder_input = Input(shape = (256,642))
encoder           = UNet_encoder(Autoencoder_input)
decoder           = UNet_decoder(encoder)
Autoencoder = Model(Autoencoder_input, decoder)
Autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mse')
```

Now, I want to make predictions for latent size input (i.e. 32 here). But Decoder part asks for skip connections C1, C2, C3 and C4. How to get rid of this issue?

```
decoder_input = (100,32) # samples, latent_size
pred_results  = UNet_decoder.predict([decoder_input, C1, C2, C3, C4])
```

But I am getting followint error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 100, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Here 2000 are number of samples used in training.